Why Don’t My Two TextFields Take 50% of the Parent’s Available Width in Material-UI Grid?
I’m using Material-UI Grid to layout two TextField components side-by-side in a responsive form, with each intended to take up 50% of the parent’s width. However, the TextFields don’t stretch properly and appear smaller than expected. Here’s the code I’m working with:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid2";

const AddQualificationForm = () => {
  const [qualification, setQualification] = useState({
    specialization: "",
    licenseNumber: "",
  });

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100vw", padding: 2, border: "2px solid blue" }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ border: "2px dashed black", width: '100%' }}>
        {/* First Grid Item */}
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          sm={6}
          sx={{
            border: "2px solid red", // Red border for the first item
          }}
        >
          <TextField label="First Name" fullWidth />
        </Grid>

        {/* Second Grid Item */}
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          sm={6}
          sx={{
            border: "2px solid green", // Green border for the second item
          }}
        >
          <TextField label="Last Name" fullWidth />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AddQualificationForm;

im want something like the attached picture:


Try setting the width of the Box-component to 100% rather than 100vw

Nope.. tried already.. still not working

You can make the grid items fill the available space with size="grow"
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {/* First Grid Item */}
  <Grid
    item
    size="grow"
  >
    <TextField label="First Name" fullWidth />
  </Grid>

  {/* Second Grid Item */}
  <Grid
    item
    size="grow"
  >
    <TextField label="Last Name" fullWidth />
  </Grid>
</Grid>

This, however, will not let you use the media breakpoints you specified. If you want to specify size based on those you would do something like this:
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {/* First Grid Item */}
  <Grid
    item
    size={{ xs: 12, sm: 6 }} 
  >
    <TextField label="First Name" fullWidth />
  </Grid>

  {/* Second Grid Item */}
  <Grid
    item
    size={{ xs: 12, sm: 6 }} 
  >
    <TextField label="Last Name" fullWidth />
  </Grid>
</Grid>


Give parent grid width a 100% value

nope still no working, I tried
